# Are iOS and Android apps sharing the same AppID considered the same app for Facebooks 'App-scoped User IDs'?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an app with a friend that uses the Facebook API - He's handling the iOS version while I'm doing the Android version.

Facebook's v2.0 API introduced "App-scoped User IDs" which means the user ids are unique to each app. Does this count for our situation, where the app is the same over different platforms?

I've look around but can't find any definite answers and don't have an iOS dev workstation setup to test this myself.

The apps are linked with the same AppID so I suspect it might be fine. Can anyone confirm this for me?